# Русский текст в javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, кодировка

Получаю с помощью AJAX запроса русский текст с сервера. Пытаюсь вывести. Получаю это: `Р­РєСЃС‚СЂРµРЅРЅР°СЏ РѕСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР°` 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как привести текст в нормальный вид.

Comment: У вас кодировка не верная

Comment: У меня так и стоит. Я так понял текст приходит с сервера уже в такой кодировке, мне нужно как-то перекодировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это проблема несоответствия кодировок символов.
Текст изначально в "нормальном" виде (UTF-8), а вот документ - в "ненормальном" (Windows-1251): поэтому и искажается отображение текста при его выводе.

Наиболее разумным решением будет использовать в документе кодировку `utf-8`, в соответствии с требованиями актуального стандарта HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body> 
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Если же проблема в некорректном определении кодировки ответа сервера** (когда данные фактически в `utf-8`, но приходят как `windows-1251`), можно ее переопределить:

```
xhrInstance.overrideMimeType('<MIME-тип>; charset=utf-8');
```

Демо:

```js
const url = 'http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo' + queryString({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=windows-1251', 
  body: 'Экстренная остановка', 
}); 

(async () => {
  console.log('Без переопределения:\n', await getRequest(url)); 
  console.log('С переопределением:\n', await getRequest(url, 
    xhr => xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=utf-8')
  )); 
})(); 


function getRequest(url, beforeSend) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
      resolve(this.responseText); 
    }); 
    xhr.open('GET', url); 
    if (beforeSend) beforeSend(xhr); 
    xhr.send(); 
  }); 
}

function queryString(obj) {
  return '?' + Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([p, v]) => `${p}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`
  ).join('&'); 
}
```

Comment: У меня так и стоит. Я так понял текст приходит с сервера уже в такой кодировке, мне нужно как-то перекодировать.

Comment: @Олег, я дополнил ответ. В демке точное воспроизведение ситуации из вопроса.